# Add Images to Flex Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4

I have a Datagrid that already gets its data from a data provider, there is a column in the grid called priority. What i want to do is if the column priority contains the value high then in an empty column in the datagrid i want to insert and image , the image being inserted depending on the value of the column priority.

Any help would be much appreciated.

thanks 
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using an itemRenderer. Check out [this link](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/20/formatting-a-flex-datagrid-control-using-a-custom-item-renderer/) for an example. Here's another quick example:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn width="30" editable="false">
  <mx:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
      <mx:Canvas horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
        <mx:Image id="myImage" x="11" source="{outerDocument.MyPriorityImage}" visible="{data.Priority > 50}" includeInLayout="{data.Priority > 50}"/>
      </mx:Canvas>
    </fx:Component>
  </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```